# Talend: How to create a table in MySql DB and populate using CSV file?

Tags: mysql, csv, talend

I'm working in Talend and trying to create a table using data from a csv file. The database already exists but it has no tables as I need to be able to create one using the Talend components. I am using MySQL.

I am seriously struggling to find tutorials on this. Please help!

Comment: Go through documentation they have detailed explanation on this, https://help.talend.com/display/HOME/Current+Documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a easy task nicely covered by the user manual, but let me give you some starting insights:

Define a database connection. This will give you the possibility to record a connection detail to the DB you can reuse. And it's easier to check, too --> http://www.etladvisors.com/2012/08/22/managing-multiple-db-env/
If you don't need dev/test/prod decoupling, you can follow just the first part of the tutorial

Now design your job like:

tFileDelimitedInput---->[some data transformation stuff]--->tMySqlOutput

Fill the "Schema" section of tFileDelimitedInput to match your CSV (columns, datatype); you'll need to fill some other parameters too (ie the separation char, the encoding...)

Finally, in tMySqlOutput select your just recorded db connection from the dropdown list and fill the table name. If you select "Create table if not exists" on Table Action parameter, the table will be automatically created following your Schema (if you need not nullable or PK conditions you must define it in your Schema as well)

Be careful! If you change the input schema coming from your tFileDelimitedInput component you need to sync the changes to your output schema (in tMySqlOutput). Talend should ask for it automatically. If it doesn't, you can click "Sync Schema" at any time inside tMySqlOutput

Comment: Thanks Gabriele B. I did get that far but it doesn't seem to be working. Would [some data transformation stuff] be mapping? I'm so new to this...

Comment: Sorry if I confused you. With [some data transformation stuff] I mean [some additional optional components you may need to do something on your data]. For example a sort, a filter, an aggregate. Ofc if you don't need any of them, just connect tFileDelimitedInput to tMySqlOutput directly

Comment: So at what point is a table being created?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I see. It's still not working. I have no idea why though :(

Comment: can you post the error message

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 pstmt_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved
 batchSizeCounter_tMysqlOutput_1 cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: that is if i use an existing connection. if i deselect that box then my error is:
`For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Street' at row 58
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
For input string: "null"
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Street' at row 24`

Comment: Having said that, my database has a table and has been populated... I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: A nice bag of common Talend pitfalls :) For the second error, be careful to fill the "Length" metadata for each of your Schema column. For the first, you need to connect your tMySqlConnector instance to your tFileDelimitedInput instance using a "On Subjob Ok" connection. What's going os is that disconnected subjobs executes on different threads (each green bacground starting component spawns its own thread). So, your DB Connection is out-of-scope of your data-transfer subjob. Using the "On Subjob Ok" signal you sequentiate the two subjobs, hence concatenating them in just one.

Comment: Yay! Ok, I got the second part of what you said there. Much more makes much more sense now! However, I still get the ' For input string: "null" ` issue as well as the `Data too long...` issue :(

Comment: For others, here is a link describing "Data too long" https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Exception%3A+Data+truncation%3A+Data+too+long+for+column , and here is a link with a scenario that writes to MySql DB: https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8122983#Raa47355